# why is "this" undefined in <script type="module">?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Playing around with ECMAScript Modules just found that calling out `this` in the "global" scope of a script with type module is `undefined` but in a normal script, it references to the `window` object

**ES Modules script**

```html
    <script type="module">
      console.log(this); // undefined
    </script>
```

**Normal script**

```html
    <script>
      console.log(this); // window object
    </script>
```

Is there any spec about this, or can someone explain me why?

Comment: Because `this` in ES6 modules *is* `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi I see, any reference?

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_browsers-scripts-versus-modules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 modules are specced such that their `this` value is `undefined`. You can see the spec definition in [8.1.1.5.4 Module Environment Records: GetThisBinding()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-module-environment-records-getthisbinding).

> 8.1.1.5.4 GetThisBinding()
>
> 1. Return undefined.

Comment: Cool !!! Thank you. I also found this http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_modules-vs-scripts